# Critical Points of the form y=x

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For the function $f(x,y)=exp(x-y)^2$. I'm asked to find the critical values and classify them as max/min. I notice that the critical values are of the form y=x. Can I conclude that since this is true then $$f(x,x)=exp(x-x)^2=1$$ and $f(x,x)=1$ does not have neither a min/max?

I understand that this means evaluating the function along the direction $v=[1,1]^T$ and that extremum on the whole is an extremum on any direction. If we can find a direction along when the critical point is not an extremum, then we can conclude this critical point is not an extremum on the whole. Is my reasoning precise?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just using second partials test but this is a special case function.

Comment: Whether or not a region can be a local maximum/minimum depends on your choice of definition for maximum/minimum.  Some definitions require that all the values nearby are strictly smaller/larger while others require all the values to be less/greater than or equal to the extreme value.  Which case are you working with?  Note that a definition is different from the test.

Comment: Just added a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that $$\forall a\in\mathbb R \;\; e^{a^2}\ge 1$$
and $e^0=1$, we get

$$f (x,y)\ge f (x,x) $$

the minimum is attained over the line whose equation is $y=x $.

Comment: Will this change to a max if we put $y=exp^-(x-y)^2$?

Comment: sorry  $f(x,y)=exp^-(x-y)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Is your function

$f(x,y) = \textrm{exp}((x-y)^2) $

or

$f(x,y) = (\textrm{exp}(x-y))^2 = \textrm{exp}^2(x-y)$ ?

In either case, you should try computing the gradient and setting it equal to the zero vector, and then analyze the solution set using the second derivative test. Most calculus books will have a justification of this technique, and you can also find it explained [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/RelativeExtrema.aspx).

Comment: First one. I did solve it I get $y=x$

Comment: You cannot use the reasoning in your question because your function is not always equal to one, only on the line $y = x.$ The function has no maximum and the domain has no boundary, so you are looking for stationary points and singular points.  Note, since your input to $\textrm{exp}(\cdot)$ is always nonnegative, you should be able to verify fairly easily that the minimum value the function can achieve is 1, and since your function is equal to 1 on the line $y=x$ that those points are all minima. The function is differentiable, so the critical points are not singular points.

Comment: Will this change to a max if we put $y=exp^-(x-y)^2$?

Comment: sorry  $f(x,y)=exp^-(x-y)^2$

Comment: @User69127 Yes. $e^{-X^2}\le 1=f (x,x) $.